# Sum between two dates with multiple text criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to compute the sum (of column Amount in the range `U3:U8`) from date (column Date in the range `S3:S8`) in the range from "1.4.18" to "31.3.19" of only Aman, Dell and Ivan (Column Description in the range `T3:T8`.

[image: Sum between two dates with multiple text criteria]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Maybe nest `TEXTSPLIT()` and  `SEARCH()` inside `SUMIFS()`. Let us know what you come up with.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Microsoft 365, here's one formula that will work:

```
=SUM(
    FILTER(
        $C$3:$C$8,
        BYROW(
            $B$3:$B$8,
            LAMBDA(arr,
                OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TEXTSPLIT(B12, ","), arr)))
            )
        ) * ($A$3:$A$8 >= $A$12) * ($A$3:$A$8 <= A13)
    )
)
```

This can be done with earlier versions, but is a bit more complicated.

First, create two **Named Formulas**:

```
numWords Refers To: =LEN(Sheet9!$B$12)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(Sheet9!$B$12,",",""))+1

seq      Refers To: =ROW(INDEX(Sheet9!$A:$A,1):INDEX(Sheet9!$A:$A,numWords))
```

You can then use this formula:

```
=SUM(
    MMULT(
        ISNUMBER(
            SEARCH(
                TRANSPOSE(
                    TRIM(
                        MID(
                            SUBSTITUTE(
                                $B$12,
                                ",",
                                REPT(" ", 99)
                            ),
                            IF(seq = 1, 1, (seq - 1) * 99),
                            99
                        )
                    )
                ),
                $B$3:$B$8
            )
        ) * ($A$3:$A$8 >= $A$12) * ($A$3:$A$8 <= $A$13),
        seq ^ 0
    ) * $C$3:$C$8
)
```

[image]

In the second formula:

`numWords` is the number of words in the "Contains Words" cell
`seq` returns an array of numbers equal to numWords (eg: `{1,2,3}`)
`MMULT` is used to convert the arrays of valid searches to a single column of values (eg similar to the `BYROW` in the first formula).

***To split the text string on the commas:** (replacing the `TEXTSPLIT` function*

```
TRIM(
                        MID(
                            SUBSTITUTE(
                                $B$12,
                                ",",
                                REPT(" ", 99)
                            ),
                            IF(seq = 1, 1, (seq - 1) * 99),
                            99
                        )
```